# UIScrollView.contentSize seems to grow with zoom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, zooming

So the contentSize of my scrollView is initially equal to the frame of my image, but it seems that the more I zoom, the larger the contentSize gets. Thus, when the scrollView is zoomed in, , there is a huge gap around it. Dynamically updating the contentSize in  - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Note: the gap is only visible vertically (i.e: above and below the imageView)

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe it is possible to update `contentSize` on the fly while `zooming`. This is because:

> A scroll view also handles zooming and panning of content. As the user
>   makes a pinch-in or pinch-out gesture, the scroll view adjusts the
>   offset and the scale of the content. When the gesture ends, the object
>   managing the content view should should update subviews of the content
>   as necessary. (Note that the gesture can end and a finger could still
>   be down.) **While the gesture is in progress, the scroll view does not
>   send any tracking calls to the subview.**

[(Apple docs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndZooming%3awithView%3aatScale%3a)

You should update your `contentSize` based on `zoomScale` *after* the user has finished `zooming` using:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                       withView:(UIView *)view 
                        atScale:(float)scale
```